# Facebook share image and text

Tags: facebook, share

This page: http://viralsport.se/4-Crazy-mal-av-Svenska-landslaget-mot-Island.html for example.

In header i have this code:

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Viralsport" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Crazy mål av Svenska landslaget mot Island" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Ett av de märkligaste målen Svenska landslaget har gjort" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.viralsport.se/4-Crazy-mal-av-Svenska-landslaget-mot-Island.html" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://gfx2.aftonbladet-cdn.se/image/10714609/485/normal/483e194e3fdfc/Ska+inte+till+aik" />
<link rel="image_src" href="http://gfx2.aftonbladet-cdn.se/image/10714609/485/normal/483e194e3fdfc/Ska+inte+till+aik" />
```

When I share on Facebook as it selects a completely different picture and no text at all. 
What have I done wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I refreshed the info in the debugger, now the correct image shows up. Just enter the URL in the debugger and you will see a button called "Fetch new scrape information" next time it does not use the correct data: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

Also, make sure the og-image follows the specification about size and aspect ratio: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/maximizing-distribution-media-content#images